# ios noob: why doesn't my view controller show the title that I have assigned in the inspector

Tags: ios, xcode

I am learning iOS by following O'Reilly Headfirst iPhone Development 2e.

I am trying to assign the title to a viewcontroller so that it looks like this: 
[image]

But even when I set the title (as shown in the picture below) the title bar is still blank when the app runs in the simulator. I am sure I am missing something really obvious, but this is all really new so don't know what box to check/setting to configure in the IDE. I'm stuck. What should I click?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to select the navigation bar and define a title. You're defining the View Controller title, it's not the same thing.

Comment: how do i select the navigation bar?

Comment: Clicking. It will be blued and you will see the header "Navigation Item" in Inspector. ;)

Comment: When I click there--I don't see that. I think what @Matt is saying is right. The storyboard does not behave like the nib.

Comment: It's not the problem. Storyboard works well. See the image: [link](http://imageshack.us/a/img23/1856/capturadetela20121016s0.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is nothing like what the book is telling you to do. It tells you to set the view controller in a nib; you're using a storyboard. It tells you to set the title of the view controller's navigation item; you're setting it on the view controller itself. In other words you're doing something different from what the book is saying to do, and then you're complaining that something different results.

Comment: yeah it is a pain. The book said "To get started, go into Xcode and choose the File→New Project option. Choose the Navigation-based application and name it DrinkMixer. Make sure that “Use Core Data” and “Include Unit Tests” are not checked." I am using a newer version of xcode which does not include this Navigation-based application option so I had to embed it in a storyboard project, based on advice elsewhere on SO. Maybe my xcode and this book are so different I should find another tutorial.

Comment: My book is still good thru iOS 5; some chapters available for free at http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/. However, (1) Navigation-Based is now called Master-Detail, and (2) remember to uncheck Storyboard if you want what you see to be like what your tutorial describes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in this way also, other than set it in the interface builder.

if you gonna define a title for uinavigation bar use self.navigationItem.title = @"your title";  <-- in viewDidLoad

if it's view controller title use:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        // self.title = @"your title";
    }
    return self;
}
```

if you are new to ios, I recommend not to use storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, per se.

I did this tutorial too, and find the book helpful. Start over and use nibs. Choose the Master-Detail template. However, if you want to keep using storyboards, follow this tutorial that tells you how to create a tableview with a drill-down:http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

It will tell you how to set the title. I suspect that you've created your navigation bar or tableview incorrectly if you can't click on the Navigation Item and see where to set 'Title' in the attributes window.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your navigation bar selected, as far as I can see now you have selected your viewcontroller and not your navigation bar. You can also double click on the navigation bar to set a title, it will appear in your attributes inspector as well.